# How to solve age word problems?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, problem-solving

Roy is now 4 years older than Erik and half of that amount older than Iris.  If in 2 years, roy will be twice as old as Erik, then in 2 years what would be Roy's age multiplied by Iris's age?

Is there any general method or are they all so confusing?

Comment: You can try forming some systems of linear equations to solve them.

Comment: Write the associated equation.

Comment: that's the way to go^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Roy is now 4 years older than Erik

$$
R = E + 4
$$

> and half of that amount older than Iris.

$$
R = I + 2
$$

> If in 2 years, roy will be twice as old as Erik

$$
(R + 2) = 2(E + 2)
$$

> then in 2 years what would be Roy's age multiplied by Iris's age?

$$
(R + 2)(I+2) = \;\; ?
$$

Then you just solve the equations.  Hopefully you can see that this method will apply to any similar problem equally well.

Comment: This cleared the concept for me! Thanks!

Comment: The answers is 48!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Set $E$ the age of Erik, $I$ the age of Iris and $R$ the age of Roy today. You are given that $$R=4+E \tag{1}$$
and $$R=2+I \tag{2}$$ if I understood correctly this one (I am not sure what "that amount" is in your formulation) and $$(R+2)=2(E+2) \tag{3}$$ and you want to find $$(R+2)\times (I+2)$$ (if I understood that correctly too). Now you can solve the system of the three equations (1), (2), (3) (please check if they are formulated correctly) in three unknowns $E, I$ and  $R$. That is the general method, with the difficulty being in the correct formulation of the given relations.

Comment: I think the second equation should be $R=I+2$

Comment: @user130512 So with "this amount" is meant this 4? It is not clear

Comment: The question definitely should have been worded better, but I think that because this is a precalculus algebra question, they will not be asking him to solve for R as a function of both E and I

Comment: @user130512 Ok, thanks, I corrected it. Seems more legitimate